# Function call as a parameter inside insert values statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert the data inside a `forall` loop. For this case, I cannot use a temporary variable and set result of the function beforehand.

The function just maps a number to a string:

```
create or replace function GetInvoiceStatus(status number)
    return nvarchar2
as
begin
    case status
        when 0 then return 'New';
        when 200 then return 'Sent';
        when 300 then return 'Accepted';
        end case;

    return '';
end;
```

when I call this function like:

```
select GetInvoiceStatus(200) from dual;
```

I get the appropriate result.

However, when I try to insert the data I get errors.
The `forall` insert:

```
forall i in 1.. INVOICE_DATA.COUNT
insert into "InvoiceAudit"
("PropertyName", "OldValue", "NewValue" (
            VALUES ('Status', (GetInvoiceStatus(invoice_data(i).status)),
                    ((GetInvoiceStatus((select "Status" from "Invoice" where "InvoiceId" = invoice_data(i).invoiceId)))));
```

However, I get the following error:

> [2023-06-01 15:02:57] [65000][6592] [2023-06-01 15:02:57]     ORA-06592:
> CASE not found while executing CASE statement [2023-06-01 15:02:57]
> ORA-06512: at "PUBLIC.GETINVOICESTATUS", line 9 [2023-06-01 15:02:57]
> ORA-06512: at "PUBLIC.INVOICESSP", line 63 [2023-06-01 15:02:57]
> Position: 5

I have double checked, and the results from invoice_data(i).Status and the other select value are both valid parameters (and have their cases covered) and return appropriate string when called outside the stored procedure.

Is the syntax somewhere wrong?
I would like to remain using `forall` if at all possible because it is much faster than a regular `for` loop.

Comment: This fails as well `select GetInvoiceStatus(201) from dual`  and shows the `*Cause:    A CASE statement must either list all possible cases or have an else clause.`

Comment: This is very well documented. [**ORA-06592**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e4100.htm#1656) *CASE not found while executing CASE statement*
**Cause**: *A CASE statement must either list all possible cases or have an else clause.*

**Action**: *Add all missing cases or an ELSE clause*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means that the parameter value (status) is not one of the cases in the case expression (which are 0, 200, 300).

If you executed this code `select GetInvoiceStatus(555) as dd from dual` you will get the same error. So, add `ELSE` clause like this:

```
create or replace function GetInvoiceStatus(status number)
    return nvarchar2
as
begin
    case status
        when 0 then return 'New';
        when 200 then return 'Sent';
        when 300 then return 'Accepted';
        else return '';
    end case;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

CASE used as a PL/SQL expression (rather than a function that returns a result, as it is commonly used in SQL) has to do *something*. If none of your conditions match, it has nothing to do:

```
DECLARE
  var_test integer := 1;
BEGIN
  CASE var_test 
    WHEN 2 THEN null; 
  END CASE;
END;
```

Throws the ORA-06592 error. To fix, add an `ELSE` to catch anything that doesn't satisfy your other `WHEN` conditions.

```
DECLARE
  var_test integer := 1;
BEGIN
  CASE var_test 
    WHEN 2 THEN null; 
    ELSE null; 
  END CASE;
END;
```

Works fine. Note again that this requirement only exists for `CASE..END CASE` used as a PL/SQL expression. Most of the time we see `CASE` it's a function and doesn't have to have an `ELSE` like this (it will return `NULL` if no WHEN clauses are matched). But the PL/SQL expression is a different animal.

I would also add that you shouldn't be using a user-defined function for this. Simply use the SQL function `CASE` or even `DECODE` inside your SQL directly to do the translation.